# How to change title of a UINavigationBar from another NavigationController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a SideMenuController (https://github.com/dogo/AKSideMenu) which handles three NavigationViewControllers:

- One in center named ContentVC
- Two sideMenus

  - leftMenuVC which changes ContentVC
  - rightFilterVC which is for filtering content.

[image: Scheme]

When user presses an item on the rightFilterVC, 
the **ContentVC content should be "refreshed" - not the controller itself.** (title in NavigationBar, and content it self). The ContentVC class should stay the same.

I can re-instanciate the ContentVC from rightFilterMenu, but then the rightFilterMenu is responsible for instanciating the ContentVC. This should be the part of the leftMenuVC. Only the leftMenuVC should be able to change ContentVCs. The rightFilterVC is normally used to change static variables in a Filter class. The Filter class is accessible from every ViewController and holds parameters which are used for api calls.

```
// Typical rightFilterMenu change looks like this:
Filter.name = self.selectedName

// can do that in rightFilterVC
// but should only be part of leftMenuVC
self.sideMenu.contentViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentVC1")


// something like this does not work either
self.sideMenu.contentViewController.customNavBar.setTitle(self.filter.name)
self.sideMenu.contentViewController.setNeedsLayout()
self.sideMenu.contentViewController.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Should I implement an "Filter"-observer within each ContentController? So they update itself if something changed in rightMenuVC? Or is there another approach?

Answer (score 1):

Your logic ins't working because you are instantiating a new VC , different from the VC on the screen:

```
self.sideMenu.contentViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentVC1")
```

You probably can solve this problem using delegate instead.

1 - Create the delegate protocol with the "updateNavigationTitle" function inside:

```
protocol SideMenuDelegate { 
    func updateNavigationTitle(_ newName : String)
}
```

2 - Set the ContentVC as a SideMenuDelegate:

```
    class ContentVC : SideMenuDelegate ... {

        func updateNavigationTitle(_ newName: String) {
            self.customNavBar.setTitle(newName)
        }
    }
```

3 - On your side menus controllers , add the delegate as a property:

```
var delegate: SideMenuDelegate?
```

4 - When you call the side menu, set the delegate (probably on the viewDidLoad function) :

`self.delegate = ContentVC` (get the reference of the current ContentVC, do not instantiate a new ContentVC)

5 - And finally, from one of the side menus:

```
self.delegate.updateNavigationTitle("My new Content VC navigation Title")
```

Comment: Do I have to made a second delegate to the "rightFilterVC"? The rightFilterVC does not know which controller is in the center! I have to tell him that. My real "setNavBarTitle"-func has two params, one for the "ControllerNameTitle" and one for the "FilterName (Subline)". As I understand, your example (thanks!) is expecting that both sides are setting the ContentVC and also the title. I have also delegates on the `SideMenuController` (willHide, willShow, didHide, willHide). Maybe I can use them instead of creating yours? I also may have to create a delegate for passing the ControllerName to it.